# Avoiding Replacing Constant Reference With a Literal When Compiled

Tags: java, compile-time-constant

I've discovered that when a constant (static final, initialized at compile time) is declared in one project, references to it in another project are replaced by a literal when compiled.

It seems the only way to avoid this and have references refer to the constant field rather than the literal is to declare the constant in a class (as opposed to an interface) and omit "final," e.g.:

```
public class MyClass {
   public static String MY_CONSTANT = "The constant value";
 }
```

Unfortunately I coded an interface full of constants before I understood this, and now to effect a change in a constant, we have to identify all projects that refer to it and recompile them. I'm afraid something will slip through.

Also, a constant without the "final" modifier isn't exactly constant, is it?

Is there a compile option that can suppress the replacement of constant references by literals?

Comment: You discovered a hole in your knowledge about java. And for the record: yes, this is somehow a problem in larger setups, **but** this is a well-known problem. Any reasonable **build system** should be able to deal with that; by **understanding** the dependencies and the need to recompile all classes that need to ...

Comment: We had done the same mistake not so long ago.
We than had change the Interface to have getter-Methods. 
and an implemting class.
Please take a look add "Effective Java" from Joshua Bloch. Item 19:
"Use interfaces only to define types"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need something that isn't a [compile-time constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). For example, method invocations aren't. So just adding `.intern()` at the end of each literal will make it escape the rules. Then each referring site will have to ensure the target type is initialized and read the current value.

A compiler option that changes this behavior is impossible because it would violate the Java Language Specification.